# Deleting multiple rows from 1 to p

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete multiple rows from 2 to p.

normally, if you want to delete rows from 2 to 1234 you do this:

```
Rows("2:1234").EntireRow.Delete
```

So I thought I should try that:

```
dim p as long,
p = (Range("N2").Value)
Rows("2:p").EntireRow.Delete
```

But I've got an error. (**type mismatch**)

Anyone has an idea what to do?

Of course I can also delete rows this way

```
for i = 2 to p 
    Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
next i
```

but I think it will take more time - tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is a variable. When you put it within quotes, it is treated as a string. Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim p As Long
p = Range("N2").Value
Rows("2:" & p).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Thank you very much, now it works much faster:)